# Running a macro in the background

Tags: excel, vba

When running a macro in Excel, Excel focus its attention fully on the macro to complete and you cannot do anything in the workbook but wait. Is it possible to run a macro (in the background) in a workbook while working in the workbook as well?

I tried to run the below code with `DoEvents` but it is not giving me what i want. Excel still hangs when the code is running,

`While (True)
For i = 1 To 500000
    Cells(i, 1).Value = 1
DoEvents
Next i
Wend`

Comment: It may be helpful if you provide more details about what actually macro would do in the background.

Answer (score 1):

> The DoEvents function surrenders execution of the macro so that the
>   operating system can process other events.

You can make use of DoEvents

```
While(True)
    'Write your code here.
    DoEvents
WEnd
```

Comment: This is very useful but in my case it does not give me what i want. When i try to work in the workbook, the macro stops. The macro should continue.